# BB10 merge 2 bar files in 1 application

Tags: android, mobile, native, blackberry-10, blackberry-c++

I have an application that devide in 2 parts

1. native bb code that access device information like call log and running a bg service
2. android code that contain the ui

The question here how can i merge these 2 app in one bar files.

Comment: "bb code" -- blackberry code?  bbcode, forum software stuff?  Code for bb guns?

Comment: Blackberry native c++ code

Comment: BB-10 native?  I added BB-10 as a tag.